# GWT: How to make sure a javascript is run after the GWT page is constructed

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, gwt

I have a javascript file main.js. The main.js contains something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     Cufon.replace('#myform p.head', { fontFamily: 'HelveticaNeueLT Std Thin' });
     ......
});
```

I suppose what this does is to run this method after the whole page is loaded and apply the change to the css elements.

But what I found out is that this only works when the script is loaded before all the HTML elements, e.g.:

```
 <body>
   HTML......
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
 </body>
```

However, if this script is put on top of all the HTML, it stops working:

```
 <body>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
   HTML......
 </body>
```

This happens on both static HTML and the GWT page. Because my GWT always put the generated HTML stuff at the end of all the body contents, the script is always before the HTML, hence is does not work. For example, my HTML for GWT module is like this:

```
  <body>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
  </body>
```

And after compiled, the generated HTML from my UIBinding gives HTML page like:

```
  <body>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
       Generated HTML....
  </body>
```

My questions are:

1. Is there anyway in GWT where I can specify the generated HTML goes
   between some statements in the  tag.
2. Is there any other ways instead of $(document).ready I can guarantee
   it is called as the last thing happened in a page load?

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I find it strange that the script doesn't work as intended when moved up in a static page (`$(document).ready(…)` is supposed to wait for the `</html>` to be reached –aka `DOMContentLoaded`– before running the function passed to it), it's not the reason it doesn't work with your GWT application (in other words, your diagnostic is wrong).

GWT's `onModuleLoad` also runs at `DOMContentLoaded` (or later, but never earlier) so you probably have a race condition between your app's `onModuleLoad` and jQuery's `$(document).ready(…)`. You could try putting the `<script>` for your GWT app *before* the `main.js`, but because `onModuleLoad` might run after `DOMContentLoader` anyway, there's no guarantee it'll work (even less in a crossbrowser way).

I think you'd better remove the `main.js` or replace the `$(document).ready(…)` with a simple `function`, and call `Cufon` (and/or whatever else you were doing in `$(document).ready(…)`) from within your GWT app, at the moment appropriate for your needs (i.e. after you attached the `#myform p.head` element/widget to the document).

The easiest way to do that is to put the script in a JSNI method and then call that method where appropriate. Just make sure you use `$wnd.Cufon` instead of `Cufon` (and similarly for all other *globals*), and replace all occurrences of `document` with `$doc` and `window` with `$wnd`.

```
public static void cufon() /*-{
  $wnd.Cufon.replace('#myform p.head', { fontFamily: 'HelveticaNeueLT Std Thin' });
}-*/;
```